# How can I get the URL of an HTTPResponse

Tags: android, url, httpclient, httpresponse

how can I get the URL of an HTTPResponse?
I tried:

```
response.getHeaders("Locations")
```

But I obtained:

```
11-15 21:14:03.355: INFO/System.out(880): [Lorg.apache.http.Header;@43ea9568
```

Comment: HTTP responses don't have URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe be thinking of redirecting the client to a new url in which case you want to set `Location` not `Locations`

Requests have URLs, responses are just data packets sent back to the client.

Comment: Assuming the Location header is what you want try: `response.getLastHeader("Location").getValue()`

Comment: @Alexandre thanks for the edit but I did actually mean set - using the `Location:` header is a common way to redirect output.

Comment: Sorry. I though it was a typo. But how does setting the `Location` header makes sense in this context? The OP is dealing with a *response* object from an http *client* library.

Comment: @Alexandre The question itself didn't make sense as you noted in your comment on the Q - I was wondering if instead of mixing request/response, the OP had mixed get/set. The only reason I came to this conclusion is that the OP mentioned the `Location:` header which is included in responses for redirection. until the OP clarifies further, I don't think there's much more we can do to help

Comment: Location:, in addition to its use with redirection, is the header used when your POST operation has created a new object with its own URL.  This is part of the design of REST systems.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for(Header header : response.getHeaders("Location")) {
  System.out.println("Location from connect:" + header.getValue());
}
```